# Accordion link affecting the child anchor links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, accordion

Below is the link for the code demo

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkZN6/)**

There are 2 questions

1. Click on the links of the first accordion I(Link1 | Link 2 | Link 3), why is that acting weird
2. And the sub-child div in the 1st accordion content is not visible in the output. (`<div>This div is not visible in the output</div>`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link http://jsfiddle.net/zkZN6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

```
$('.accordion > li > a').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

Define **class name** to the DIV instead  of `.accordion div{display:none}`. Write like this:

```
.accordion .extended{display:none;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zkZN6/2/

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you defined `$('.accordion a').click(function(){` in your javascript which affects all  tags under the class name called "accordion". you need to define another classname just specific for the "accr1,accr2,accr3...etc" and define another javascript for them.

Comment: what about that invisible div?

Answer (score 0):

Well as Tugkan said all the links are affected by `$('.accordion a').click(function(){` that's why it is behaving strange and as far as the division is concerned the property display none is applied to it see in the inspect element.

Do something like this to make division appear :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkZN6/3/)

```
style="display:block;"
```